# Moment Generating function hard example!

Tags: random-variables, exponential-function, expectation, moment-generating-functions

X is a random variable with density
$$f(x)=2e^{-2x+2}  , x\geq1$$
and 0 otherwise.

Determine $Mx(θ)$, the moment generating function for X, and the values of θ for which $Mx(θ)$ is defined. Use $Mx(θ)$ to determine $E(X^2)$

Working:
I know that

$Mx(θ) = E(e^{\theta x})= \int_{0}^{\theta}e^{\theta x}fx(x) \ dx =\int_{0}^{\theta} e^{\theta x} (\lambda e^{-\lambda x})  \ dx$
$=\frac{\lambda}{\lambda-\theta}$

But I am unsure how to use this with the more complicated $f(x)=2e^{-2x+2}$ . Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

You have

$$ M_{X}(\theta) = E(e^{\theta X}) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{\theta x} f(x) \, dx = 2 \int_{1}^{\infty} e^{\theta x} e^{-2x + 2} \, dx = 2 \int_{1}^{\infty} e^{(\theta - 2)x + 2} \, dx. $$

Can you determine for which $\theta$ the integral converges and to what value?

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I still don't really understand what it means by 'the values of $\theta$ for which $Mx(\theta)$ is defined'

Comment: The integral $\int_{1}^{\infty} e^{(\theta - 2)x + 2} \, dx$ is defined as the limit of $\lim_{M \to \infty} \int_{1}^{M} e^{(\theta - 2)x + 2} \, dx$. It is possible that this limit (intuitively, the area under the graph of $e^{(\theta  - 2)x + 2}$ from $x = 1$ to $x = \infty$) doesn't exist or is infinite - in which case we say that the integral doesn't converge and $M_X(\theta)$ is not defined.